# Using regular expression to parse text to prevent XSS

Tags: javascript, regex, xss

I'm trying to parse a blob of text in `html` format, that only allow `bold` `<b></b>` and `italic` `<i></i>`.

I know it nearly impossible to parse the html text to secure XSS. But given the constraints only to `bold` and `italic`, is that feasible to use regex to filter out the unnecessary tags?

Thanks.

--- Edit ---

I meant to do the parsing on the client side, and render it right back.

Please test your code against this, before jumping into conclusion.
http://voog.github.io/wysihtml/examples/simple.html

BTW, why is the question itself get down voted?

--- Closed ---

I picked @Siguza 's answer to close this discussion.

Comment: As far as I understand it isn't the tags that are the problem it is all the other stuff that can be input that you need to protect against.

Comment: You can't do this using JavaScript on the browser. To do it you'd have to do something server side; before it has a chance to get to the client (otherwise someone could inject custom javascript to remove your JavaScript removal).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Regardless the front end, backend should always handle the input itself. With that being said, the reason I filter it on the front end is that I dont want to send the text back to the server and wait for the sanitized data come back. It delays the program, not a good UI experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and probably most secure way I can think of (doing this with regex) is to first replace all `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively, and then explicitly "un-replace" the `b` and `i` tags.

To replace `<` and `>` you just need text substitution, no regex. But I trust you know how to do this in regex anyway.
To re-enable the `i` and `b` tags, you could also use four text replacements:

```
&lt;b&gt; => <b>
&lt;/b&gt; => </b>
&lt;i&gt; => <i>
&lt;/i&gt; => </i>
```

Or, in regex replace `/&lt;(\/?[bi])&gt;/g` with `<$1>`.

## But...

...for the sake of completeness, it actually *is* possible with just one single regex substitution:

Replace `/<(|\/|[^>\/bi]|\/[^>bi]|[^\/>][^>]+|\/[^>][^>]+)>/g` with `&lt;$1&gt;`.

I will not guarantee that this is bullet-proof, but I tested it against the following block using [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com), where it appeared to hold up:

```
<>Test</>
<i>Test</i>
<iii>Test</iii>
<b>Test</b>
<bbb>Test</bbb>
<a>Test</a>
<abc>Test</abc>
<some tag with="attributes">Test</some>
<br/>
<br />
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you do this with regex? Kind of. You have to write a regex to find all tags that are not b or i tags. Below is a simple example of one, it matches any tag with more than 1 character in it, which only allows `<a>`, `<b>`, `<i>`, `<p>`, `<q>`, `<s>`, and `<u>` (no spaces, no attributes and no classes allowed), which I believe fits your needs. There may well be a more precise regex for this, but this is simple. It may or may not catch everything. It probably doesn't.

```
<[^>]{2,}[^/]>
```

Should you do this with regex? No. There are other better, more secure ways.

Comment: I understand I could use a sanitizer javascript library, but the library I found are too big for me to load on the front end. That's way I want to using regex to filter out the contents. BTW, `<a>` will lead to XSS i.e. `<a href="#"onclick=alert(1)>fail</a>`.

Comment: @LinDong You can't do this on the client side.  It's not secure and won't protect the user from XSS.

Comment: @LinDong I meant you should prefer serverside parsing to client side, as well and non-regex to regex. And like I said, tags with attributes would be matched, so literally only <a> could get through, <a href="#"> would be matched.

Comment: Please see my comments, both front/back end will handle the input. But I dont want to send the request back and forth to increase the delay. I would prefer to parse it on the client side and display, then after ajax call to replace the backend sanitized text.

Comment: @LinDong So what stops an attacker from using the JavaScript they inject to keep that Ajax call from firing?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Theres no way for me to prevent all the misc code from client side, but I try my best to prevent that from happening. Anyway, that is off the topic, I need you to show me the code. I need to see an example that only allows `<b>`, `<i>` and will be XSSed, please try against this site, this is RTE that purly reside on the client. http://voog.github.io/wysihtml/examples/simple.html

Comment: @LinDong I'm telling you it's impossible to stop XSS under these circumstances. In fact, it's a waste of time to try to stop XSS under these circumstances; all user input should be validated and cleansed on the server side.

Answer (score -2):

1. Parse out tags, replace with a special delimiter (or store indices).
2. [XSS sanitize the input.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)
3. Replace the delimiters with tags.
4. Make sure you don't have any mismatched tags.

XSS sanitizing needs to be done server-side - the client is in control of the client-side, and can circumvent any checks there.

I still maintain that the OWASP Cheat Sheet is sufficient for XSS sanitization, and replacing **only** empty bold and italic tags shouldn't compromise any of the rules.

Comment: I would stay away from making suggestions like "You should be fine" if the OP hasn't stated whether or not they're doing it on the serverside or clientside. if they try to parse it on the client side; they won't be able to protect from XSS.  And there are a whole category of XSS attacks that can circumvent this: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet